# Initializing objects and building CoreData relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I'm trying to build the relationships for an object. But I guess I'm not understanding everything properly. When I set them, it looks like they all get set properly (that is, the relationships are found). But when I loop over them later, some of them (not all) don't exist.

I have an `Report`, which has many `LineItems`. Each inspection item one `Rating`. When I create an inspection, I'm copying data from another object, `ReportMaster`. ReportMaster also has MasterLineItems which also have Ratings. But as of right now I can't guarantee that the relationship between MasterLineItems and Ratings is correct. Therefore when I copy the ReportMaster's attributes for the Report I also do a fetch for the Rating.

I have a method within Report to check to see if all the LineItems have Ratings. But I can never get it to return true.

My question is, how should I properly be setting these attributes, or what am I doing wrong? Thanks. (The relationship building as at the end of the code block)

```
# Creating Report
Report *report = [Report object];
[report setWithMasterReport:masterReport];

# Report.m
- (void)setWithMasterReport:(MasterReport *)masterReport {
    self.name = [masterReport.name copy];

    [self addLineItems:[LineItems copyItemsFromMasterReportItems:masterReport.masterLineItems]];
    NSLog(@"items have ratings: %i",[self lineItemsHaveRatings]);
}

- (BOOL)lineItemsHaveRatings {
    NSArray *lineItems = [[self lineItems] allObjects];
    BOOL t = TRUE;
    for (LineItem *lineItem in lineItems){
        if (lineItem.rating)
            t = t && TRUE;
        else
            t = FALSE;
    }
    return t;
}

# LineItem.m

+ (NSSet*)copyItemsFromMasterReportItems:(NSSet *)masterLineitems {
    NSMutableArray *lineItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[masterLineitems allObjects]];

    // go through one by one and replace inspectionFormItem with the inspectionItem copy
    for (NSUInteger i; i < [lineItems count]; i++){
        LineItem *lineItem = [InspectionItem object];
        [lineItem setWithMasterLineItem:[lineItems objectAtIndex:i]];
        [lineItems replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:lineItem];
    }

    return [NSSet setWithArray:lineItems];
}

- (void)setWithMasterLineItem:(MasterLineItem *)masterLineItem {
    self.name = masterLineItem.name;
    self.ratingID = masterLineItem.ratingID;

    Rating *rating = [Rating findFirstByAttribute:@"myID" withValue:self.ratingID];
    if (rating)
        [self setRating:rating];
}
```

When I run that I get

```
items have ratings: 0
```

Another part of this question is, in these "init" methods (`setWith...:`) should I be copying the attribute or not? If so, should I be copying the relationship too? I just want a pointer to the object, right?

Side note: these are CoreData objects and I'm using RestKit which is why I get the `findFirstByAttribute:withValue:` helper method.

Thanks for any help.

### Update

```
- (BOOL)LineItemsHaveRatings {
    NSArray *lineItems = [[self LineItems] allObjects];
    BOOL t = TRUE;
    for (LineItem *lineItem in lineItems){
        if (lineItem.rating)
            t = t && TRUE;
        else {
            t = FALSE;
            Rating *rating = [Rating findFirstByAttribute:@"myID" withValue:LineItem.ratingID];
            NSLog(@"[No Rating Found] %@",lineItem);
            NSLog(@"[Rating to find]  %@",rating);
        }
    }
    return t;
}


[No Rating Found] <LineItem: 0x8200e40> (entity: LineItem; id: 0x8200d00 <x-coredata:///LineItem/t05319326-640E-4DA5-B619-EB20621E3D533> ; data: {
    rating = nil;
    ratingID = 13903;
})
[Rating to find]  <Rating: 0xec356a0> (entity: Rating; id: 0xec31520 <x-coredata://4EE6AD5A-CC34-460A-A97A-0909454126A4/Rating/p15553> ; data: {
    myID = 13903;
    name = "APPA (Northwestern Memorial Hospital)";
    rangeItemRatings =     (
        "0xec3a2d0 <x-coredata://4EE6AD5A-CC34-460A-A97A-0909454126A4/RangeItemRating/p2952>",
        "0xec3a2b0 <x-coredata://4EE6AD5A-CC34-460A-A97A-0909454126A4/RangeItemRating/p2950>",
        "0xec3a2e0 <x-coredata://4EE6AD5A-CC34-460A-A97A-0909454126A4/RangeItemRating/p2953>",
        "0xec3a2f0 <x-coredata://4EE6AD5A-CC34-460A-A97A-0909454126A4/RangeItemRating/p2954>",
        "0xec3a2c0 <x-coredata://4EE6AD5A-CC34-460A-A97A-0909454126A4/RangeItemRating/p2951>"
    );
    ratingType = "0xec368b0 <x-coredata://4EE6AD5A-CC34-460A-A97A-0909454126A4/RatingType/p112>";
    ratingTypeID = 1;
})
```

It is strange to me that the other relationships are built and stayed connected. But this one doesn't. ... oh. I didn't have the relationship set to be a to-many relationship. Oops.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RestKit but I'd start by looking at what happens with an ` } else { ` after the `if (rating){` test.  Your lineItemsHaveRatings requires valid ratings for everything, so it would be good to know about any cases where one wasn't returned.

Comment: Whoops. That is just a typo on my part. I was printing out error / validation statements in my code locally.

Comment: @PhillipMills What kind of things should I be looking for in the cases where one wasn't returned? Locally I just print out the rating and see that it really does exist.

Comment: Whether or not it happens would be interesting.  If it happens, then there would seem to be something odd about that MasterLineItem.  (I say that based on your code's assumption that `Rating findFirstByAttribute:` will always provide something valid.)

Comment: @PhillipMills - THANK YOU! I had overwritten the `description` method to make things print nicely. I removed it and looked closer. Only the rating relationship was every being messed up. I looked at the CoreData model... I had it set to be a one-to-one relationship. Changing it to a one-to-many relationship solved my issue.

Comment: All add an answer and close it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to changed the relationship type for the `Rating`.